# tray has stopped working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system-tray

I am developing a windows app with C++ that has a system tray icon.
I have a user that keeps getting an error message saying " tray has stopped working"
Is there any way to know what caused this message to appear?

Comment: Have the debugger attached to it when it crashes.

Comment: It is a problem to attach a debugger, this is a client machine.
I was wondering what situation causes this.

Comment: are u using log file in your app

Comment: yes, I do have a log file

Comment: then u can try log your system tray functions as far as possible

Comment: You could generate a minidump for them to send you so you can debug it on your machine.

Comment: I already did that, I went so far as to have a wrapper function around my system tray functions that always outputs something. I'm still not sure in which case windows decides to show the error message.
I would like to stress that this error message comes from windows and not from my application directly.

Comment: Try to give us some more info - your question is too broad..

Comment: Window associated with the tray is not processing the message check the window whether its processing message using SPY++